# Defining a Macro for Defining Functions

Tags: c, arduino, macros, c-preprocessor

I have functions of the following form:

```cpp
void onPulse10(){
  pulseList.push_back(10);
}

void setupMeterInput10(){
  pinMode(10, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(10), onPulse10, RISING);
}
```

I use these to attach interrupts on pins. My problem is that I have around ten pins that I would like to watch for using interrupts. All do the same thing the only difference is the number: instead of 10 it will be 10-20. How can I define a macro such as `SetupPin10()` that will expand to the above, so I can have 10 setup lines instead of same 2 functions copy pasted 10 times?

Comment: What about a template?

Comment: Please refrain from macros for this.  Can you instead pass the value `10` as a parameter and use only 2 functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use templates for this, this is  for an embedded platform and call backs can not receive parameters so thats why I need to define one function for each callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [token pasting](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) (`##`) to accomplish this.

```
#define SetupPin(n) void onPulse##n() { pulseList.push_back( n ); }
```

Then simply use

```
SetupPin(10)
```

Which will expand to

```
void onPulse10() { pulseList.push_back( 10 ); }
```

Comment: Is it possible to expand both functions with the same macro ? cantinue with the second function after the first one?

Comment: @HamzaYerlikaya - Yes, the macro can expand into anything - including two functions.